What does the book cover of Fetter's Applied Hydrogeology represent?
This is the book cover of "Applied Hydrogeology" by C. W. Fetter:

I'm curious to know what the image in the book cover represents.

IMO the hydrogeologic map in the background - well, it's rather a map of wells, bore holes, some streets and creeks etc - depicts the northwest of the Seymour Recycling Corp. superfund site near Seymour, IN (Fourth Five Year Review Report Seymour Recycling Corp. Superfund Site check p.26 or Sixth Five-Year Review Report For Seymour Recycling Corp. Superfund Site Jackson County, Indiana p.20)
